# two values for one name in input

Tags: php, html

I have one input (type radio) that I want to insert it 2 values, something like that:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value1="value1" value2="value2" />
```

And after draw each value seperated with PHP.

There is a way to do it? (And no.. I dont want to insert input with type="hidden")

Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by this:

"that I want to insert it 2 values, something like that:

And after draw each value seperated with PHP." ? I don't get it

Comment: I don't think you included the example there. Can you check your question again?

Comment: radio buttons aren't meant to support multiple input values.

Comment: Example was hidden (jay for markdown ;) ), lifted it.

Comment: not sure what you are asking?  example of how you want it to look? 1 radio input, normally indicates 1 value, not sure what you mean by 2 values.. .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, not the way I would do it, but you could use a delimiter for your value(s)

```
<input type="radio" value="Value1|Value2" name="two_values" />
```

Then, in PHP, just `list($value1,$value2) = explode('|', $_POST['two_values']);`

**EDIT**
As @user387302 said, you would obviously be limited to not having any values containing your delimiter, for example `value="One|PipedVariable|andAnother"` would not work to extract two values of "One|PipedValue" and "andAnother"

Comment: wow! good idea!
I thing it is going to work. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value1#value2" />
```

and then split on "#" (or any other symbol) server-side?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, can you set the value of your radio to something like "value1-value2" and then in your php just seperate value1 from value2 with explode(). You could use any other seperator other than '-' too.

Edit

based on your exmaple:

```
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="value1-value2"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't do it.

You need either a hidden input (which you say you don't want) or use `value="value1,value2"` and then `explode` in the PHP script.

Answer (score -1):

Use this :

```
<input type="radio" name="name[]" value1="value1" />
<input type="radio" name="name[]" value1="value2" />
```

returns array