# Pass two variables through checkbox in php

Tags: php

Through checkbox I want to pass  &  values. how can I do that. I can only pass one value. I am trying but its not working

```
while($row_tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
        <tr class="success" style="font-size:12px;">

         <td > <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="chk_val" value=" <?php echo $row_tbl['Course_ID'] ?> " id="in" onclick="test()" /></td>

            <td > <?php echo $row_tbl['Course_ID'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Course_Title'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Section'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Time'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Day'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Dept'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Capacity'] ?>&nbsp/&nbsp 0 </td>


                    <?php

                  }
```

Comment: What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: Use proper tags. This has nothing to do with Laravel nor CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass multiple values, you need to create multiple checkbox with the same name (as an array)

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="chk_val" value="value1"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="chk_val" value="value2"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="chk_val" value="value3"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="chk_val" value="value4"/>
```

In your controller,

```
$values = $request->check; //the array of checked inputs.
```

Then you can loop through it

```
foreach($values as $value) {
    ...
}
```

**Update**

Accodring to the chat discussion you want to send 2 different fields per checkbox. In your checkboxes, put both fields like this

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <input type="checkbox" 
        name="check[]" 
        class="chk_val" 
        value="{{ $course->id }}-{{ $course->section }}"/>
@endforeach
```

Pay attention to the value here. I added a delimiter `-` that will be useful in the controller. In controller now

```
public function selectedCourses(Request $request)
{
    ... //whatever you do for validation

    //loop through selected courses
    foreach( $request->check as $values ) { 
        $values = explode("-", $values); //split where we added the dash
        $id = $values[0]; //the course ID
        $section = $values[1]; // the course section

        ... do what you want here with that information
    }
}
```

And voila!

Comment: Thanks but My job is different. Here i use one check box and through that i want to capture two variable
<td > <?php echo $row_tbl['Course_ID'] ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row_tbl['Section'] ?> </td>

Comment: You are trying to pass to values to a single input. Let me tell you already it's IMPOSSIBLE. All you do now is compact your values as a string or an array and give them to your input. You cannot pass 2 separate values through the same input.

Comment: See here how to use a delimiter to send compact your values into a single string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407317/two-values-for-one-name-in-input

Comment: I am basically making a course registration app then . how cal i fix that

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. All I know is you want to pass many values in a single input. What are you trying to do? Maybe you should redesign it to use multiple checkboxes?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixmkvwzxtxxtrko/Capture3.PNG?dl=0
I think it will give you some idea. I want to store only two fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137614/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-mithun).