# variable with spacing

Tags: php

I have an variable like this: `exercise = Rug hol-bol maken` it has spacing I know this is not a proper way of using this as img src and http request. But for now I would like to keep it this way.

I have a form where I send the name of the input to the database and than I use the input name as title, image, and video src. Like this:

`<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="oefening1" value="Rug hol-bol maken"/>`

Maybe I can set a `name value` for title: Rug hol-bol maken and for the src an other name value? Is it possible to set two value attributes on 1 input?

The image is getting picked up with the `exercise` variable but when I want to play the video of the exercise lik this: `'http://www.example.com/fysioWebapp/videos/' + exercise + '.mp4'` this is not working ofcourse because the http request will make that `rug hol-bol maken` like this: `example.com/fysioWebapp/videos/Rug%20hol-bol%20maken.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I'm clear on your requirements but you can use *urldecode* on the incoming query string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

```
<?php
// Not sure how you access the variable but something like...
$decodedName = urldecode($_GET['oefening1']);
```

Comment: I think more something like this" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407317/two-values-for-one-name-in-input

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a delimiter if you want to store 2 values in the same attribute, like `|` for example, but it is not very robust (breaks if one value contains the delimiter)

Better, you can add custom attributes to your tags, it is usually done with a "data-" prefix (don't know if this syntax comes from jQuery or not). You can easily retreive values from jQuery or plain javascript. The little downside is if you use them on forms, the second value will not be passed automatically. You can for example add a hidden input for this value.

```js
//by jQuery
console.log($('#cb1').data('altvalue'));

//by javascript
console.log(document.getElementById('cb1').getAttribute('data-altvalue'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="oefening1" value="Rug hol-bol maken" data-altvalue="boo"/>
```